# CheckBox Field Similar to Content But not Displayed

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

Is there a member in a CheckBox class that can store any data like **Content** but at the same time is not displayed in the End-User window?

Right Now the output looks like this:
[output preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHfLO.jpg)

I would like to get rid of the part marked in red, that shows name of the class that is Binded to Content. Comment on the right side is the member of different class, not the class binded in Content

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: C#. I am using WPF. What Im trying to do it to set Content Binding to certain class - let's say "Element", but display in the End-User Window (next to the checkbox) another property e.g Element.Description. Right now it keeps showing full Element class name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. **CheckBox.Tag** contains  data that is not being displayed next to the box in the End-User window.

Answer (score 0):

What I think you want, is to have a separate binding for the `Content` (the text displayed) and for the `IsChecked`. Something like this:

```
<Checkbox
    Content="{Binding Element.ContentName}"
    IsChecked="{Binding Element.SomeBool}" />
```

Then if you want something more sophisticated to happen when a checkbox is checked/unchecked, you can make the `SomeBool` setter call a method, which executes some code:

```
public class ElementModel 
{
    (...)
    private bool _someBool;
    public boolean SomeBool
    {   
         get { return _someBool; }
         set
         {
             _somebool = value;
             // call your method
         }
     }
 }
```

This isn't exactly functional code, but you get the point...

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However it is not the solution I was looking for. I have edited my question to be more specific. Any further help, much appreciated.